# How to use npm country codes

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, backbone.js, requirejs

Hin I am new in node.js. I already created my project in cordova cross platform Mobile Application. Now I want to install npm country-codes package "https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-codes". I already install this from command line But I can't get country codes. It's display error

```
"Uncaught Error: Module name "countryCodes" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

I don't konw how to solve it please help me.
I simple use this from npm doc. In my Project I used backbone.js and require.js

```
var countryCodes = require('countryCodes')
console.log(countryCodes)
```

Comment: Do you have installed country codes module? `npm install country-codes`

Comment: YeahI installed it "npm install country-codes". But I can't see any folder or files in my root folder

Answer (score 1):

Pay notice that this page module in NPM says the following:

This module is **deprecated**.

Please use the country-data package instead of this country-codes module. It is more well-maintained and the original author of this repository/package has decided to focus on that module instead. Here is a link to it: https://github.com/OpenBookPrices/country-data/. If you need help with a migration, please file an issue on that repository and tag @niftylettuce.

The second thing you need to do is to install it with npm command and it should appear under your node_modules folder

```
npm install country-codes
```

The error that you are experiencing is created by the common.js library which is the Node.js loader library.
This occurs when there is a require('name') call, but the 'name' module has not been loaded yet.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it